# Need help with Lennox MPD 35RPM propane fireplace

Tags: gas, fireplace, propane

I moved into my current home in August of 2017. I tried looking into getting this thing up and running, but got frustrated and gave up. I still haven't, and want to give it another shot. This propane fireplace is 20k btu Max. We have never used it, and from what I understand the previous owners of the house never did either. I've contacted several propane companies in the area, and they seem more interested in selling me propane service than anything else. I don't plan on using this often, and just don't want to sign up for service. I'd like to get a 100lb tank, or maybe two with an automatic switch type thing in between, which I have seen some people do. Right now there is nothing but a stub out outside the basement. What do I need as far as regulators etc. for a fireplace of this size? The fireplace is on the upper level, and is piped down to the basement and out of the wall.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Are you sure it would work, and not leak propane, if you hooked it up? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: I would assume that it would need to be hooked up to see if there are leaks. The same goes for whether or not it works. I need to get to that point before I can answer those very important questions. I know I need a regulator and a pigtail at least, but what kind, etc. I have no clue.